# why do my patterns go missing in high DPI bitmap export?

Tags: inkscape, svg

As part of something I have made, I have a large shape with a pattern fill for each of my shapes. However, when I export it at large resolutions, it renders the first third or so, and it abruptly stops. How can I fix this without reducing the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance it is a bug or a memory problem.

One option would be exporting groups of objects (layers) and compose them later in Gimp.

---

I have not inkscape on this computer, but simply hide some layers and export the visible ones to PNG with transparent background.

**In an extreme case make a copy** of your original file and delete some layers. Open the original and delete diferent layers and export the rest.

Comment: Thanks, so how would I export the layers?

Comment: I edited a bit the anwer.